# Oracle date column value as 0000

Tags: sql, oracle

We need to store 00-00-00 in date datatype in Oracle column. But Oracle doesn't allow.

Are there alternate representations or ways to store it?

Comment: That seems to be a bad idea. Use NULL for unknown/unset.

Comment: What does that value mean? It is not a valid date.

Comment: And Oracle is absolutely right, because there is no month "zero" and no day "zero" in the Gregorian calendar (don't know about others). Why would you want to store something like that? What not just store `NULL`?

Comment: @spencer7593: it's not a valid date. Regardless of the data type ;)

Comment: `We need to` should be `We want to` and the response should be `What's the REAL (underlying) problem statement?  Because this is probably the wrong solution`

Comment: This sounds remarkably like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  What is it that you're *actually* trying to accomplish?  Does it have to be done with invalid dates?

Comment: @spencer7593: Oracle (or any sensible RDBMS) will not allow invalid values in a `date` column. That's the whole point of using the correct data types: avoid invalid values to be stored. It's the same as asking to stored the date `2016-02-31`

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does allow you do insert the date 1st January 1AD:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( date_column ) VALUES ( DATE '0001-01-01' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant, but I was once "required" to store 0th April 1996, 0th  1996, etc.. The *real* requirement was that these were fiscal transactions that could not be assigned to a single day or month respectively (e.g. journal vouchers).

The solution was to use real dates (1st April 1996, 1st Jan 1996), and to add another column that gave the "scope" of the record -- "D", "M", "Q", "Y".

So if all the transactions for 1st Apr 1996 were required, a date_scope = 'D' predicate could be added to my_date = date '1996-04-01' to ensure that only daily transactions were retrieved.

If all the transactions for April 1996 were required ...

```
my_date between date '1996-04-01' and date '1996-04-30' and
date_scope in ('D','M')
```

Comment: Or fence-post values.  A value for one day could be `2016-06-01 -> 2016-06-02`, and a value for a month could be `2016-06-01 -> 2016-07-01` *(using -exclusive- end value, rather than inclusive, makes the maths easier and also allows any degree of granularity; `2016-06-01 12:00 -> 2016-06-01 13:00` for an hour range)*.